# ChartJS x axis title not visible when axis position is centered

Tags: javascript, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

When position is not centered, the title is visible.
[image: not centered x-axis]

But the title disappears, if the x-axis position is centered.
[image: position center]

Here is my Chartjs options.The documentation doesn't seem to have viable options to address this issue.

```js
const options = {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,

    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'linear',
        min: 0,
        max: MAX_AGE,
        grid: {
          display: false,
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'xaxis title',
        },
        position: 'center', // what can I do to view the x-axis tile when axis is centered.
      },
      y: {
        min: -10,
        max: 10,
        grid: {
          display: false,
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'yaxis title',
        },
      },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using a version of chart.js lower as 3.5 since this was a bug that has been resolved in the 3.5 release with this pr: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/9413

So to resolve your issue you will need to update to the latest version of chart.js

Answer (score 0):

The Chart Title options have evolved quite a bit in v2 of Chartjs as well. I found that the title was hidden entirely until I added padding - for one example

```
options: {
      plugins: { 
        title: {
          display: true, 
          text: "Title" ,
          padding: {
              top: 10,
              bottom: 10
          },
          font: {
            size: 24,
            style: 'italic',
            family: 'Helvetica Neue'
          }
        }
      },
      ... other options here
}
```